# How would you read 1000 bytes of a data in file in php?

Tags: php, file, fread

How would you read 1000 bytes of data from a log file in php ? I tried using

```
fread ($fp, 1000)
```

but issue is if file has less than 1000 bytes then it won't read at all ? 
Other issue is it reads chunks of 1000 bytes but in the end if there is any chunk left which is less than 1000 bytes, it ignores it?

```
$all_data = array();
while (($data = fread($file_handle, 1000)) !== false && strlen($data) == 1000) {
$all_data[] = $data;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you read the [PHP documentation](http://dphp.net/fread)? Quote: `Reading stops as soon as one of the following conditions is met: [...] EOF (end of file) is reached`.

Comment: I have read and I am not sure what I am doing wring in the condition apart from strlen($data), probably '!== false' is causing it not to read

Comment: `fread($fp, 1000)` should read 1000 bytes from your file even if its file size is less than 1000 bytes. Apart from that, byte != character - as Lee already noted.

Comment: I did try with while only ($data = fread($file_handle, 1024)), but it leaves the last few lines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the strlen() from your while loop, that is stopping it returning less than 1000 bytes, as you specifically tell it not too.

Also characters that are >1 byte each (utf-8 chars for example), will cause you a lot of issues if they appear in the file you are reading, as all of a sudden you will be reading 1000 bytes but not returning a string of 1000 characters.

Edit: Just noticed that your reading the file wrong, i just presumed it worked under certain circumstances for you, but im going to presume that it doesn't work at all.

Basically, fread does not return false if you try to read beyond the byte length of the file, it simply returns an empty string (assumingly, it detects EOF and returns immediately, but i cant say i know every single thing of the php internals).

Quickest solution is too change it too:

```
while (($data = fread($file_handle, 1000)) !== false && !empty($data)) {
```

so that it exits on the first empty return.

Alternatively, do what the documentation suggests and use the EOF test function like so (this is what you should ideally be doing, to avoid any issues).

```
while (!feof($file_handle) {
   $all_data[] = fread($file_handle, 1000)); 
}
```

Note: I'm not sure why you are storing it into an array. Array's are bound by the same memory limits as a generic string variable, so if your intending to use this to overcome `file_get_contents` memory limits, it won't work.

Comment: Even if I remove the strlen condition it is not giving the last chunk.